# How to simplify get and set of deep properties

Tags: c#

Does anybody know how to rewrite this to avoid repeating myData.wwwww.xxxxx.yyyyy.zzzzz?

```
public string DeepString{
get => myData.wwwww.xxxxx.yyyyy.zzzzz; 
set
{
   if(myData.wwwww.xxxxx.yyyyy.zzzzz != value)
   {
     myData.wwwww.xxxxx.yyyyy.zzzzz = value;
     OnPropertyChanged();
   }
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged; // = delegate { };
protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string s = null)
{
   if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(s));
}
```

Comment: Refence the last object? Or make it property

Comment: Milney has answered your exact issue, but overall it seems that responsibility boundaries are unclear, and you may have a OO design problem overall. Basically, this is a code smell to me. I don't have a proper design to propose, we probably need more info on what you need to achieve for that.

Comment: @Pac0 object orientated spaghetti OOS

Comment: This is probably the result of dealing with XML at some point during the lifecycle.

Comment: You can store a private variable referencing myData.wwwww.xxxxx.yyyyy and just go _privateVar.zzzzz instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably about as good as you are going to get...

You *could* like define a delegate/action to get/set the value and call that - but IMO that would be changing the actual behaviour too much and would look odd...

```
private String _shorterName => myData.wwwww.xxxxx.yyyyy;

public string DeepString{
get => _shorterName.zzzzz; 
set
{
   if (_shorterName.zzzzz != value)
   {
     _shorterName.zzzzz = value;
     OnPropertyChanged();
   }
}
```

Or add a property on the myData object, which is => wwwww.xxxxx.yyyyy; Then reference myData.NewProperty - but then your kindof just kicking the can down the road as it were.

Comment: Probably worth to note if any of this is null, there be dragons

Comment: Yes indeed. Thats an issue with the original too though. OP - You can do ?.wwww?.xxxx?.yyyy if you want NULL to propagate up to the top instead of throwing Null Exception

Comment: _shorterName does not return a string, returns a class instance with a string zzzzz property

Comment: Yeah okay well just change String to the name of that class then... You never told us what class it was so I can't read your mind